# CSS Media Queries not respected on chrome in iOS when using text-scaling (text-zoom)

Tags: css, web, media-queries, accessibility, responsive

When using a CSS media query to set different styles depending on viewport width the media query is not respected by chrome browser running on iOS when using text-scaling/text-zoom in the browser settings.
Somehow same media query works on safari on iOS when using the text-scaling function in the browser settings.

In my understanding using text-scaling/text-zoom function of a browser will reduce the viewport width and so the media query should be respected. Somehow this is not working for chrome in iOS.

The media query is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 260px) {
      .sampleClass {
           background: red;
       }
}
```

The media query only gets respected when max-width is set higher than the normal viewport width (without text-zoom).

I do have the following viewport meta tag on my page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
```

I cannot explain why this is working for safari but not for chrome in iOS.

Comment: Have you tried defining the media query in `em` instead of `px`? It makes sense that text-scaling does not influence media-queries that are not specifically targeted at text size. Firefox probably does the same for text-only zoom. I’ll check.

Comment: No actually also Firefox takes text-only-scaling into account for the base of min-width media queries even if they are px-based.